# Perforce integration with Flex Builder / Flash Builder

Tags: flexbuilder, perforce, flash-builder

How well does the Perforce Eclipse plugin work with FB (3 and/or 4)? I've found some claims of compatibility on the internet but I'd like some confirmation of compatibility based on real experience before I bother trying it.

Comment: i'm curious if you've had any problems?  i've recently installed the Perforce Eclipse extension for Flash Builder 4.5 and everything seems to work great except that when i open an .as file it loses the syntax coloring.

Answer (score 1):

it works pretty well in my experience.  Every once in awhile I have to switch into P4V for some reason or another, but that's pretty unusual in day-to-day usage.

Comment: i'm curious if you've had any problems?  i've recently installed the Perforce Eclipse extension for Flash Builder 4.5 and everything seems to work great except that when i open an .as file it loses the syntax coloring.